# How to call a parent class's method from child class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page with a method I use a lot from content page code behinds. In those code behinds, I have a method that gets duplicated a lot, so I thought I'll put it in something I can inherit from. Unfortunately, I now can't call the method in my master page code behind from the base class. I think I should know how and I'm probably being pretty stupid today but I can't figure it out.

Here's some code! Please ignore any howling errors, I just typed this off the top of my head :)

**Master Page Code-behind**

```
public partial class Site : MasterPage
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do Something...
    }
}
```

**Content (Child) Page**

*Declarative*

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

*Code-behind*

Works

```
public class Test : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Master.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Does Not Work

```
public class Test : TestClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OtherMethod();
    }
}

public class TestClass : Page
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        this.Master.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, looking at it, I intuitively know "this.Master" can't work but I don't have any lightbulbs going off for an answer. How do I get the reference to my master page method back?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Is there any reason the method can't be placed into a helper class instead of the `MasterPage`?  For instance, a static `Utilities` class.  If you need references to the current page or controls on the page, you can pass them in as parameters to your helper method.

Comment: The method interacts with declarative UI elements in the master page (in this instance a pop-up alert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast this.Master to the type Site in order to access methods defined on Site : MasterPage.

```
public class TestClass : Page
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        ((Site)this.Master).MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that seems to work. Bonus question... what if TestClass was in a reusable class library? That would lose the ability to 'find' Site. Any workaround or should I just live with including TestClass in all my web application projects? Hope that makes sense!

Comment: You could include both Site and TestClass in the same reusable assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast to the the type of the your MasterPage class first (in this case Site) and then you can call the public methods defined within the code behind class ...

```
public class TestClass : Page
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        ((Site) this.Master).MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, but the type cast as shown is redundant so your solution is identical to this.Master.MyMethod()

Comment: @Richard: No, `this.Master.MyMethod` won't work because `Page.Master` is typed only as a `MasterPage`, which doesn't have a `MyMethod()` method on it. I think he meant to type is as a `Site`, which is the name of the specific master page class you're using.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it should be your master class derived from MasterPage i.e. Site.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast this.Master to Site :

```
((Site)this.Master).MyMethod();
```